# why `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java` is required?

Tags: java, security

I created a class "String" and placed that in package "java" [ actually i wanted to create *java.lang* to see which class is loaded by classLoader as

> Once a class is loaded into a JVM, the
>   same class (I repeat, the same  class)
>   will not be loaded again

quoted from oreilly ] . But that thing later, why on running this class i am getting
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: **java**

For which security reason java is not allowing me to have a class in **java** package? What one could do if there will not be no such check?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

User code is *never* allowed to put classes into one of the standard Java packages. That way, user code cannot access any package-private classes/methods/fields in the Java implementation. Some of those package-private objects allow access to JVM internals. (I'm thinking of `SharedSecrets` in particular.)

Comment: In principle I agree with the analysis of the risks posed, but note that you can only access package-private stuff if your class is in a package with the same name and it is loaded by the same ClassLoader.

Comment: No, this isn't the reason. User code *can* access private members in `java` classes through the Reflection API. And what about code under the `javax` package? The JVM does allow new classes to be defined there.

Comment: @Rogerio: Using the reflection API to access private stuff requires a `SecurityManager` check. Obviously, if you have no security manager installed, all bets are off anyway.

Comment: Never say *never* - it is possible to write your own `java.lang.Object`; you just must be sure to correctly add its location to the bootclasspath

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger If you can add something to the bootclasspath (or into the endorsed extensions directory), that wouldn't qualify as "user" code. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, these types of restrictions are in place to enforce the Java sandbox. That is, running untrusted code in a trusted environment. Such as running an applet from some site (that you don't necessarily trust), on your computer (the trusted environment) in your browser. The intent is to disallow untrusted code from gaining access to package-private stuff which could help it escape the sandbox.

Normally these restrictions are enforced by the SecurityManager, so they shouldn't happen when you run your own application on the command-line (unless you explicitly specify to use a SecurityManager). When you control the environment, you could just go and edit the String.class definition inside the rt.jar of your Java (and you can, technically anyway, not sure what licensing says). As I said the restrictions are normally in the SecurityManager, but this particular rule about java.* packages is in the ClassLoader class.

To answer your question: My guess is that java.* check is there because of 
a) historic reasons
b) somewhere in the Java core there's a check on the name of the class, something like: All class that start with java.* get special treatment.

However, consider that even if you managed to create a class called java.lang.String, it would not be the same class as the java.lang.String defined by the Java core. It would just be a class with the exact same name. Class identity is more than just the name of the class, even though this can be tricky to perceive unless you really play with ClassLoaders.

So a class loaded by the application classloader in the package java.lang, would not have access to the core java.lang package-private stuff.

To illustrate this, try to create a class called javax.swing.JButton with a main method and execute it. You'll get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`. That's because java finds the "real" JButton before your class, and the real JButton doesn't have a main method.

In a Java standalone application you might be able to go around this restriction by calling one of the private native defineClassx methods directly via use of reflection and setAccessible.

BTW: The core java.lang.String is guaranteed to be loaded before your code ever executes because it's referenced everywhere, you would not get there first with your user code. The JVM gets set up to a degree before ever even trying to load your class, let alone execute it.

Comment: This is the best answer, but there is more to it. With use of the `java.lang.instrument` API through a "Java agent", it is possible to *redefine* any class loaded by any class loader, including the `java.lang.String` class defined by the bootstrap class loader.

Comment: @Rogerio, also how do all the other commentators think one uses -Xbootclasspath (e.g. to use jsr166 for java.util.ForkJoinPool)? How would one have compiled the jsr jar?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot have "java.*" package names.  This is actually hard-coded in the Java core so you cannot even grant a security manager permission to work around it (cf. ClassLoader::preDefineClass(...))

Comment: To be more accurate, actually you can have 'java' package like 'import xxx.java', instead leaving 'java' at the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

`java` is a reserved package name. Only classes inside the JVM can reside in this package.

If anyone could write in the Java package, that could result in libraries arbitrarily replacing core Java classes by their own implementations. That could result in a lot of thinks, from breaking core Java features to execution of malicious code.

Answer (score 2):

A program could bypass security measures if a program could override JVM core classes with trojan versions.  For example, String is used practically everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Probably during refactoring/patch applying/etc. you have added to package name word 'java', which is usually a folder that contains packages.

So you could end with the structure:
src->main->java->java.com.yourpackage.name

It might also happens for test:
src->main->test->java->java.com.yourpackage.name

Verify it in your IDE and remove "java." part

Answer (score 2):

From the [`ClassLoader.defineClass(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain)) javadoc:

> ...The specified class name cannot begin with " java. ", since all classes in the " java.* packages can only be defined by the bootstrap class loader

and

> Throws: ... SecurityException - If an attempt is made to add this class to a package that contains classes that were signed by a different set of certificates than this class, or if the class name begins with " java. ".

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from `java.lang.ClassLoader`'s `preDefineClass` method:

```
/* Determine protection domain, and check that:
    - not define java.* class,
    - signer of this class matches signers for the rest of the classes in
      package.
*/
private ProtectionDomain preDefineClass(String name,
                                        ProtectionDomain pd)
{
    ...

    // Note:  Checking logic in java.lang.invoke.MemberName.checkForTypeAlias
    // relies on the fact that spoofing is impossible if a class has a name
    // of the form "java.*"
    if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
        throw new SecurityException
            ("Prohibited package name: " +
             name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
    }

    ...
}
```

Please note that `java.lang.ClassLoader` is an abstract class, meaning that a subclass (say,  `SecureClassLoader`) will actually implement it. However, the `preDefineClass` method is `private`, so it cannot be overridden by a subclass.

`preDefineClass` is called by the `defineClass` method, which is `protected final`. This means `defineClass` is accessible to subclasses and they can call it, but they won't be able to change its implementation.