# java classloader runtime error in netbeans

Tags: java

When I run my project it shows this error

```
run:
`java.lang.SecurityException:` Prohibited package name: java.course
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

**What can i do to solve this problem ?**

*Note:-Please simplify explanation because I'm still initially structured in the programming department and I am still in the tutorial.*

Comment: You might need to include some code. it says `java.course` package. what is the code in the class?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490555/prohibited-package-name-java

Comment: did you try to read exception message?

Comment: Fixed format and added request as note in bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use 'java' as name of a package. So java.course as name of the package isn't allowed. Try renaming the package