# How do I run a Java class in a package?

Tags: java

I have two java classes as follows

`App1` without a package:

```
class App1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("App1 hello world...");
    }
}
```

`App2` in a package:

```
package java.java.package1;    
class App2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("App2 hello world...");
    }
}
```

I can compile them both:

```
D:\javaTest>javac App1.java

D:\javaTest>javac App2.java
```

However, I can only run the first one:

```
D:\javaTest>java App1
App1 hello world...

D:\javaTest>java java.java.package1.App2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/java/package1/App2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.java.package1.App2
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: java.java.package1.App2.  Program will exit.
```

How can I run `App2`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you put the *source* in an appropriate directory hierarchy matching the package name (`D:\javaTest\java\java\package1\App1.java`), and compile/run from the root of the hierarchy (`D:\javaTest`), you wouldn't have this problem:

```
D:\javaTest>javac java\java\package1\App1.java

D:\javaTest>java java.java.package1.App1
App2 hello world...
```

You can also compile using the `-d` option so that the classes are moved into such a directory hierarchy:

```
javac -d . App2.java
java java.java.package1.App2
```

Note you shouldn't use a package name starting with `java`, and later versions of the JDK will throw a SecurityException. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804442/why-java-lang-securityexception-prohibited-package-name-java-is-required) for more information.

Comment: In addition to what Chuck Norris said: When you compile and you're at the root of the directory hierarcy, you must use `/` instead of `.`. When you run the program, it's reversed: use `.` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 4):

You create a new directory.  This is the directory containing your work, and is not the start of your packages.

For instance, I create folder /terri to start.

I then create the folder structure /clarie/andrea under it.
My package is going to be called claire.andrea in this example.
Normal package names start with com and then a company name or something like that (or java for standard java packages, so don't use that: like java.lang.*).

In the andrea folder, I create a java file called Saluton.java with the class Saluton (which just print hello).  The class name and the filename must match.

To compile, from the terri/ folder:  javac .\claire\andrea\Saluton.java 
This will create a Saluton.class in the \terri\claire\andrea\Saluton.class

To run: (again from /terri), I do:  java -cp . claire.andrea.Saluton
Which says, use class path from my current directory.
My main program is in the package claire.andrea and the Class name is Saluton.

Here's the run:
\terri
   java -cp . claire.andrea.Saluton

"Hello World".

To sum it up, the package name much match the underlying directory structure.
The file (if it references a package) must live inside the directory stucture it is refering.  If I compile Saluton.java in /terri with package claire.andrea I have not found a way to run it, it does compile fine.

Also, the filename for the class must match the public class in that file.

To run, package.Class.  In general, packages are not capitalized and Classes are.

Comment: Jerry Ludwig alias terri A bit late I am. `I WISH YOU HAD BEEN MY JAVA TEACHER`. The most neatest and cleanest solution regards to ubiquitous CLASSPATH i've ever encountered, although my knowledge of java is very minimal and tried to learn many times and needless to say, discarded my effort many times. :) Wishing you all the best 'n good luck. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `-d directory` Options..because

> Set the destination directory for class files. If a class is part of a
>   package,
>       javac puts the class file in a subdirectory reflecting the package name, 
>       creating directories as needed. For example, if you specify -d c:\myclasses 
>       and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is called 
>       c:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.

Answer (score 0):

App2 needs to be in the java/java/package1 directory.  In java, the package name and the directory for the source code must match.  Did you not get a compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is your classpath value by below command in command prompt 
echo %CLASSPATH%

check where your class is getting created. 
to compile a java source program you need to check the path you are giving , whether java file is available there or not.