# Main class not found,even though its there

Tags: java

```
package p1;

class a {
    public static void main(String[] argument) {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

And when I type `java p1.a` in command prompt, it always say `Main class not found`? Why so?

Can any one help me out? Why this is happening? Is the syntax correct?

Comment: how did you compile it and where does the p1 folder reside

Comment: it was on the desktop,and i complied after changing the directory to the folder,and then java p1.a

Comment: If it is desktop first open the cmd in desktop then compile it by javac p1/a.java and run it by java p1.a remember dont go inside the folder p1 and try the commands

Comment: You actually don't specify the package name. See this link for more details. [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html#comp]

Comment: @Jonk it doesnot matter as long as the file contains only one class

Comment: @M.Sharma Yeah, as I mentioned I was off to read the JLS to find out for certain, and you're right.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `javac` first.. `javac` generates a `.class` file.  And try using the full (absolute) path when using `java` command.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032590/how-to-run-the-java-class-with-has-package-name)

When you create a package, you have to compile the package with `-d` option in javac. Then try executing the main class.

Answer (score 1):

First as there is a `package p1;` you need to create the folder `p1` and put the file inside it then as you said if you  folder `p1` is in desktop, then open the cmd in desktop then compile it by `javac p1/a.java` and run it by `java p1.a`