# decode "compiled Java class data, version 52.0" text from file

Tags: java, encoding

I have a file without extension but I used an online site to know the type of this file. It says the file contains  "compiled Java class data, version 52.0".

The content of the file that I need to read here

```
 ˛∫æ4)


  
<init>()VCodeLineNumberTablemain([Ljava/lang/String;)V
StackMapTable
SourceFileHelloWorld.java    
SYNT{SBERAFVPF_101} !"#$%&'(
HelloWorldjava/lang/Objectjava/lang/Stringlength()IcharAt(I)Cjava/lang/SystemoutLjava/io/PrintStream;java/io/PrintStreamprint(C)V!  
*∑± 
«rL=+∂¢g+∂>a°m£
`í>ß?A°M£
`í>ß*n°z£
dí>ßN°Z£  
dí>≤∂Ñßˇó±*
```

I just need to make this file readable and get the output from it 
What is the encoding type used or is there any online site that can read it.

Comment: Try searching the web for a Java class file decompiler and run your file through it and you'll end up with Java source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compiled Java class, not some text with an encoding. Compiling means translating human readable text into instructions a PC can understand. So the file contains such CPU instructions similar to machine code, called "intermediate language" or "byte code".

Use `java.exe` [to run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032590/how-do-i-run-a-java-class-in-a-package) and see the output. Be aware that running a program of an unknown person is dangerous. It could delete files etc.

You can't get the source code back, but you can use a [Java Decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) to get close to the original.

Answer (score 1):

The comment

```
SourceFileHelloWorld.java
```

suggests this is a Java "Hello, World!" program ([*e.g.*](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/hello-world)). The long line in the middle

```
HelloWorldjava/lang/Objectjava/lang/Stringlength()IcharAt(I)Cjava/lang/SystemoutLjava/io/PrintStream;java/io/PrintStreamprint(C)V!
```

suggests the program prints "HelloWorld." That would be the output.