# Why I can not create package name like java.basic?

Tags: java

```
package java.basic;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int जानिए = 7;

        System.out.println(जानिए);

    }


}
```

Above class is compiling but after running getting exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.basic
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: This is dumb question for one who knows class loader architecture and security :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804442/why-java-lang-securityexception-prohibited-package-name-java-is-required

Comment: try changing your name to "Barack Obama" and apply for a Washington D.C. driver's license...

Comment: Please look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533102/what-strategy-do-you-use-for-package-naming-in-java-projects-and-why?rq=1

Comment: As this question has already been asked before more than twice, i think it is better to be closed as Duplicate

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html):

> Packages in the Java language itself begin with **java.** or javax.

`java.` is not for you, the English alphabet has 26 letters. Use them to generate names other than `java`.

Also see [`java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html):

> Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java
>   programming language.

It's for Java code, and it's imported by default in every code.

Comment: Do packages have to be written with english characters?

Comment: The docs doesn't mention any restriction about that.. But I think we should all write in English since that's how the world is communicating :) at least for now..

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise your classes will get access to [default (no modifiers) / `protected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) members of standard JDK classes which are not meant to expose its internal details to the developer.

Prohibiting custom classes in `java.*` packages forbids you from exploiting such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing the use of a user created package named java would allow access to package-private fields, methods and constructors.

Answer (score 1):

`java` is a reserved package name. Only classes inside the `JVM` can reside in this package.

If anyone could write in the `java` package, that could result in libraries arbitrarily replacing core Java classes with their own implementations. That could result in a lot of things, from breaking core Java features to execution of malicious code.