# Is there any way i can count number of elements landing in same Bucket in HashSet

Tags: java

Is there any way i can count number of elements landing in same Bucket in HashSet.
I wish to write a program that can count no of elements landing in same bucket in HashSet

Comment: @user1121883 That's not correct. `HashSet` is built on `HashMap`, which re-hashes the hashcodes provided by `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`. The HashMap ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry)) contains an array (called `table`) of Entry objects, and each Entry has a `next` field, which can be used to form a linked list of entries for that bucket.

So you can count the number of elements by inspecting these data structures, following the chain of Entries and counting them.

`table` has default (package) access, i.e. it is non-public, so you will need to use reflection to 'break into' the class by setting the access to public. This process is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java), for example.

Alternatively, you could create your own version of HashSet, based on the JDK source code, but with public access to the fields that you need to inspect.

Comment: That would require accessing non public members of HashMap, which can only be done with reflection.

Comment: You can also place your *inspection-code* in the same package as the `HashMap` (i.e. `java.util`). The you do not need reflection but can access the `table` property directly. Not pretty, I know but reflection is not pretty either ;)

Comment: Yes, that's probably much easier.

Comment: @DNA Can you elaborate by taking some example

Comment: Found [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804442/why-java-lang-securityexception-prohibited-package-name-java-is-required), it is **not** allowed to put classes in the *java*-package so unfortunately that will not work.

Comment: @DNA So, I took the liberty to remove that part from the answer.